# .NET Linq to SQL: select average with where-clause

Tags: linq-to-sql, average

I'have a table with movies, which has an integer attribute called ranking. I'd now like to retrieve the average ranking from all movies containing a certain actor.

Dim q2 = (From p In dc.Movies Where p.actlist.Contains(actor.name) Select p.ranking).Average()

This query doesn't work - Overload resolution failed because no accessible "Average" accepts this number of arguments. Without the Where-Clause it runs fine.

How to combine the Average function with Where-clause? I couldn't find any helpful example on MSDN and the internet ..

Comment: Is actlist a list of strings or a list of actors?

Comment: actlist is a text attribute with my movies table. It contains an xml-styled string of all actors in a movie, like <actlist><actor>Actor 1</actor><actor>Actor 2</actor></actlist>. 

Dim q1 = (From p In dc.Movies Where p.actlist.Contains(actor.name) Select p).Count() 

returns the number of movies a certain actor is in - this query is working fine ...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly no results so it can give no average; try

```
Dim q2 = (From p In dc.Movies Where p.actlist.Contains(actor.name) Select p.ranking).Count() == 0 ? 0 : (From p In dc.Movies Where p.actlist.Contains(actor.name) Select p.ranking).Average();
```

Comment: That would cause a runtime error (Sequence contains no elements), not a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code:

```
Dim avgRanking = (From m in dc.Movies _
                  Where m.actlist.Contains(actor.Name) _
                  Select m.ranking).Average(Function(a) Convert.ToInt32(a))
```

And this should also work:

```
Dim avgRanking = (From m in dc.Movies _
                  Where m.actlist.Contains(actor.Name) _
                  Select CInt(m.ranking)).Average()
```

The problem is the type of `Movie.ranking`. The result of your query is and `IEnumerable` of `tinyint`. There is no overload of [`Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx) for this.

Comment: This one is not working, build failed with error 'Name' is not a member of 'Char'. :-( Actlist is simply a string with xml-formatted content.

Comment: In that case my answer is not very useful :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to achieve my desired result?

Comment: Type of Movie.ranking is tinyint.

Query with Enumerable.Average breaks with "Overload resolution failed because noaccessible 'Average' can be called without a narrowing conversion ..."

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out by myself:

Dim q3 = (From a In dc.Movies Where a.actlist.Contains(actor.name) Select a).Average(Function(r) r.ranking)

But this one throws an execption if an actor isn't in any movie. So I had to put it in try..cast.